# Why does the order of classes in my html make a difference?

Tags: jquery, class

If an element with a certain class is selected I want to add 1 to a variable.  You can see in my code for each of the p elements there are two classes: 'p-choice' and either 'a', 'b', 'c', or 'd'.  If the class with the letter is first it works, but if not it doesn't.

```
<div class='choices' id='choices1'>
    <p class='a' class='p-choice'>Choice A</p>
    <p class='p-choice' class='b'>Choice B</p>
    <p class='p-choice' class='c'>Choice C</p>
    <p class='p-choice' class='d'>Choice D</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var score = 0;

    function selecting() {
        $('.choices p').on('click', function() {
            $(this).closest('.choices').find('p').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            if ($(this).hasClass('b')) {
                score += 1;
            }
        });

        $('.submit').click(function() {
            $(this).prev('.choices').find('p').off('click');
            $('.score').text('Score is ' + score);
        });
    };

    selecting();
});
```

Comment: You can't have multiple class attributes in an element. Use one class attribute and separate the classes with spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each attribute, like class, can only be used once for an element. Instead of

```
<p class='a' class='p-choice'>Choice A</p>
```

you should add both class names as one class attribute:

```
<p class='a p-choice'>Choice A</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ordering of attributes makes no difference. You code doesn't work because you can only have one `class` attribute per element - exactly the same as any other attribute. You need to separate each class with a space:

```
<div class='choices' id='choices1'>
    <p class='a p-choice'>Choice A</p>
    <p class='p-choice b'>Choice B</p>
    <p class='p-choice c'>Choice C</p>
    <p class='p-choice d'>Choice D</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, right!  Thanks.  Both answers were equally helpful.  I wish I could check both.